# Not getting response from server on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am new to iPhone programming. Using the code below I send a request to the server but I am not getting output. Can anybody tell me what is mistake in this code?

```
NSString *soapMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                           "<soap:Envelope \n"
                           "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \n"
                          "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"\n"
                           "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope\">\n"
                           "<soap:Body>\n"
                           "<OnlineStatus xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org\">\n"
                           "<CafeName>CyberCafeName</CafeName>\n"
                           "<FromDate>9/4/2012</FromDate>\n"
                           "<ToDate> 5/5/2013</ToDate>\n"
                           "</OnlineStatus>\n"
                           "</soap:Body>\n"
                           "</soap:Envelope>"];
    NSLog(@"%@",soapMessage);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebidmanagerdemo.com/gjHouseOnline/xml/XMLDataService.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/OnlineStatus" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if(theConnection) {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
    NSLog(@"%@",msgLength);
```

I am getting this output error message in the console:

```
 2013-05-20 17:28:26.447 NewC Newcafezee[1166:11303] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
<soap:Body>
<OnlineStatus xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
<CafeName>CyberCafeName</CafeName>
<FromDate>9/4/2012</FromDate>
<ToDate> 5/5/2013</ToDate>
</OnlineStatus>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
2013-05-20 17:28:28.355 NewC Newcafezee[1166:11303] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Header><soap12:Upgrade xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap12:SupportedEnvelope qname="soap:Envelope" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" /><soap12:SupportedEnvelope qname="soap12:Envelope" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" /></soap12:Upgrade></soap:Header><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode><faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.CheckHelperVersion()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
2013-05-20 17:28:28.357 NewC Newcafezee[1166:11303] fsdfsd
```

This original soap request

```
POST /gjHouseOnline/xml/XMLDataService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.ebidmanagerdemo.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/OnlineStatus"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <OnlineStatus xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CafeName>string</CafeName>
      <FromDate>dateTime</FromDate>
      <ToDate>dateTime</ToDate>
    </OnlineStatus>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you please post your original SOAP structure?

Comment: Have you implement NSURLConnectionDelegate Methods?

Comment: Please try adding '/' at the place of '\' in 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope\'

Comment: You should at least `start` your connection, but that's a synchronous one. Maybe you'd better try with `AFNetworking`, it's simpler to use.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated line

```
"xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope\">\n"
```

to

```
"xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
```

and its giving me response

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><OnlineStatusResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><OnlineStatusResult /></OnlineStatusResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I accept its empty but at least its not error. The data may not be available for specified parameters.